# Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor - Vuex with Vue 3

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

I'm trying to use Vuex with Vue 3. Here is my code in main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        counter: 0
    }
});

app.store(store);
app.mount('#app');
```

When trying this, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor
```

I have tried using the syntax recommended in the official Vuex docs but this does not work either. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What are your exact versions of Vue and Vuex?

Comment: Looking at my package.json they are vue ^3.0.0-0 and vuex ^3.5.1

Comment: The `package.json` is not a reliable way to check the exact installed version. That said, it looks like you have Vuex 3 when you need Vuex 4. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next#vuex

Comment: vue 3.0.0-rc.7 specifically

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs because you are calling `new Vuex.Store` as is done for **Vuex 3**.

If you are using **Vue 3**, you must install **Vuex 4** by issuing:

```sh
# npm
npm install --save vuex@next

# yarn
yarn add vuex@next
```

Then build your store and "inject" it to the Vue instance as follows:

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import { createApp } from 'vue';

const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      count: 1
    }
  }
})

const app = createApp({ /* your root component */ });

app.use(store);
```

Refer to Vuex docs for more details:

[Vuex 4 for Vue 3](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#vuex-4-x-for-vue-3)